# ERROR: django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 47: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django

How to solve problem
{% if page == 'login'%}
another html were is login form
{% else %}

here c r f token
       {{form}}
       Button to register
                 
{% endif %}

Comment: Provide the code of this template, please.

Answer (score 0):

First you should provide code in your question else nobody is able/wants to help you.

From the error I think you have a problem with 'if else'.
This is how 'if else' in DTL (Django Template Language) should be made (as example I have the value 'viewer' which is a number):

```
{% if viewer == 0 %}
   <p>No viewers</p>
{% elif viewer == 1 %}
   <p>1 viewer</p>
{% else %}
   <p>{{ viewer }} viewers</p>
{% endif %}
```